# How long is the access_token from notion-api valid?

Tags: notion-api

I'm working on an integration for notion-api and I couldn't find how long is the access_token returned from their OAuth valid. Is it always valid?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developers.notion.com/reference/authentication):

> Requests use the HTTP Authorization header to both authenticate and authorize operations. The Notion API accepts bearer tokens in this header. Bearer tokens are provided to you when you create an integration. If you're creating a public OAuth integration, the integration also receives bearer tokens each time a user completes the OAuth flow.

Looks like unless you have an option in the Admin Dashboard to select the duration, it won't expire. Contact the admin of your workspace to check that option.